# get files/folders not written within a specific date range

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

Whats the powershell command for finding files in a folder that do not meet a criteria of date range for the `Get-Childitem` filter of `LastWriteTime`.

So, check to see if a directory has files that DO NOT contain any files that have `LastWriteTime` between 01/10/2012 (1st Oct) to 25/10/2012 (25th Oct).

I want to display the folders that DO NOT have any files that are in that range...that way I know they are old and the whole directory can be deleted.

example of this is:

Folder1 - some files written within October - ignore this whole folder and do not display these in the results

Folder2 - NO file has `LastWriteTime` written in the month of October and so this folder and files should be displayed.

I know this can be done with `Get-ChildItem` and I am stuck on the bit below..

```
Get-ChildItem E:\LogArchive -Recurse | Where-Object{$_.LastWriteTime.......?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple solution off top of the head is this:

```
Where-Object{ $_.LastWriteTime -lt $startDate -or $_.LastWriteTime -gt $endDate }
```

where `$startDate` is `01/10/2012 (1st Oct)` and `$endDate` is `25/10/2012 (25th Oct)`.

Problem with this approach is that it does not account for time factor in the `[datetime]`. So in your example, if you have `25-Oct-2012` as an upper bound, it will return files created at `25-Oct-2012 9:00`, which you may not want.

Below code calculates `[datetime]`'s with time part truncated, based on the input `[datetime]`, and builds the month-to-date date range of `($dayStart, $dayEnd)`:

```
$entry_date = "20-Oct-2012 9:00" #to feed current date, use this: Get-Date
$dayEnd = Get-Date $entry_date -Minute 0 -Hour 0 -Second -0;
$dayStart = Get-Date $endDate -Day 1;
$dayStart, $dayEnd
```

For this sample code, here is the output:

```
Monday, October 01, 2012 12:00:00 AM 
Saturday, October 20, 2012 12:00:00 AM
```

Notice this approach is flexible, because you can set `$entry_date` to either `Date` or `String`, and it may or may not have time part - it will work in all those cases. You can then have this code in `Where-Object`:

```
Where-Object{ $_.LastWriteTime -lt $dayStart -or $_.LastWriteTime -ge $dayEnd.AddDays(1) }
```

Notice how `-ge $dayEnd.AddDays(1)` fixes the issue when comparing `25-Oct-2012` to `25-Oct-2012 9:00`.

Comment: that seems to work but I get an error of the below:Bad argument to operator '-gt': Could not compare "02/09/2012 20:00:02" to "23/10/2012". Error: "Cannot convert value "
23/10/2012" to type "System.DateTime". Error: "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."".
At line:1 char:112
+ Get-ChildItem E:\LogArchive -Recurse | Where-Object{ $_.LastWriteTime -lt "01/10/2012" -or $_.LastWriteTime -gt <<<<
 "23/10/2012" }
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : BadOperatorArgument

Comment: @lara400: If you specify `Date` as a `String`, make sure you convert it to [datetime] and be careful to put it in the same format your culture expects it. Or you can just use this format `[datetime]"25-Oct-2012"` - should work in all cases. Or use [datetime]::ParseExact.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
[datetime]$startDate = "10/01/2012" # or $startDate = get-date -Date  1/10/2012
[datetime]$endDate = "10/25/2012"   # or $endDate   = get-date -Date 25/10/2012

 ? { $_.LastWriteTime -lt $startDate -or $_.LastWriteTime -gt $endDate }
```

Comment: How is your answer principally different from mine?

Comment: @Neolisk it shows the cast to an object [datetime] needed for the comparison.

Comment: It was not in the original question, so not a significant difference, IMHO.